# When to use \\.\c: and when to use c:?

Tags: windows, symlink

If the symbolic link created for device1 is `\\??\device`(kernel),when accessing it,should be `\\.\device`(user space),why?

The symbolic for `C:` should be `\\.\c:`,why `\\.` can be omitted?

Comment: @Borealid Yes, Windows has symbolic links.

Comment: @Borealid: Windows has symbolic links in its object namespace, the registry, and now filesystems (as of Vista). This particular instance is an object namespace symlink.

Comment: @Gabe,what's the difference between `\\.\c:` and `c:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows supports two forms of file names.  There are files whose names follow the Windows naming convention (:\) and those that don't (\device\harddisk0\partition5...).  The "\\.\" prefix is applied to files that don't fit within the windows naming convention.

Internally Windows supports an object namespace whose names originate at the same root object.  The Win32 API will convert between the windows naming convention and the internal naming convention when it can.

However if you need to access a file whose name does not meet the internal naming convention, you can use the "\\.\" prefix to bypass the name conversion logic.

Note that drive letters do *not* match the windows naming convention (they don't have a \ after the drive letter) so you need to use the \\.\ form to open the drive.

There's a bunch of scaffolding to make this all work, you can see much of it with the [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) tool.  In particular notice the Global??\ namespace - note the Global??\C: symbolic link which maps to the C drive.

Comment: @Larry Osterman,so both `\.\c:` and `c:` means the same thing,one can use it alternatively?

Comment: I just notice that you said **drive letters do not match the windows naming convention**, if that's the case, could you give an example which match the naming convention?

Comment: c:\ matches the naming convention and is the root of the C drive.  c: does not match and is the C drive.  Both are needed in different cases.

Comment: And it's \\.\c:, not "\.\c:".  And they don't mean the same thing - one is legal (\\.\c:) one is not (c:).

Comment: @Larry Osterman,you mentioned that `c:` is illegal,but I just tried exploring it,and it's the same as `c:\`.

Comment: Actually it's not quite.  The Win32 path canonicalization logic may add the trailing backslash in certain circumstances but in the right context (if, for instance you're trying to open the drive and not the root folder of the drive) they're different. See the documentation for CreateFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) for examples.